# Reduced camera resolution but higher display window in python open cv

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on a project which requires to do face detection on raspberry pi. I have a USB camera to do this. The frame rate was apparently very slow. So, I scaled down the capture resolution using **VideoCapture.set()**. This decreased the resolution to *320, 214* as I set it. This increased the capture frame rate considerably but it the feed in displayed the feed on a window on 320 X 214. I want to keep the same capture resolution but I want higher size display window. I am just a beginner to python and open cv. Please help me do it. Below is the code I wrote for just a simple camera feed.

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import time

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(-1)

    cap.set(3, 320) #width
    cap.set(4, 216) #height
    cap.set(5, 15)  #frame rate
    time.sleep(2)

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow("captured video", frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(33) == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The docs show a [ResizeWindow](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#resizewindow) method, although you might have to both set up and resize the window outside your `while` loop.

Comment: I tried using `cv2.namedWindow('captured video', cv2.CV_WINDOW_NORMAL)` or `cv2.namedWindow('captured video', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)` but idle says cv2.namedWindow('captured video', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CV_WINDOW_NORMAL' but it works for `WINDOW_AUTOSIZE`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the display image to be a scaled up version of the original. If so, you just need [`cv2.resize`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void%20resize%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20dsize,%20double%20fx,%20double%20fy,%20int%20interpolation%29)

```
display_scale = 4
height, width = frame.shape[0:2]
height_display, width_display = display_scale * height, display_scale * width
# you can choose different interpolation methods
frame_display = cv2.resize(frame, (display_width, display_height),
                           interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
cv2.imshow("captured video", frame_display)
```

Comment: same as you did before but with your new resized image. I put it explicitly in the code. I also updated the names because I was using `cap` instead of `frame` which must have been confusing. Sorry.

Comment: but now it throws this error `frame_display = cv2.resize(frame, (display_width, display_height), cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
TypeError: <unknown> is not a numpy array`

Comment: Sorry I believe the problem is that interpolation needed to be a named argument. It was trying to interpret it as the destination image. I've updated the code.

Comment: @user1915729 If this worked for you, please accept it. If it didn't, please let me know and I'll try to help.

Comment: thanks dude it worked but it dropped the frame rate considerably

Comment: @user1915729 Sounds like the RPi is struggling with computation. How about trying a simpler interpolation. I believe [`cv2.INTER_NEAREST`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize) will basically do no interpolation and get the fasteset upsize possible. Does that help?

Comment: noted!! I'll let you know as soon as I do it. A lil' bit busy at the moment might take a day or two