# How to improve resolution of image?

Tags: opencv, python-2.7

```
import cv2.cv as cv
import time
from subprocess import Popen
capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
num = 0
while True:
img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
cv.SaveImage('pic'+str(num)+'.jpg', img)
if num == 500:
    del(capture)
    break
if cv.WaitKey(10) == 27:
    break
num += 1
```

I am capturing images in python language using opencv. The images captured using webcam are of 480 by 640 resolution.I need to increase its resolution.So how can I do this? The code is as follows.

Comment: As mentioned in this post,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678527/how-to-resize-an-image-to-a-specific-size-in-opencv, use cv.Resize

Comment: I recommend you use the cv2 interface which is newer and I think easier to use. If you do, check [this Question/Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22059934/377366) which covers camera capture and also resizing using cv2. I'd mark as duplicate of that one but it hasn't been accepted so I can't yet.

Comment: Do you mean: How to combine several images into one image that has a higher resolution and is still of good quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using VideoCapture class's set function you can change the resolution to the sepecific value. Here's a sample c++ program:

```
#include"opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
VideoCapture cap(0);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080);
Mat frame;
cap >> frame;
imwrite("test.jpg",frame);
}
```

You can find similar function in python as well. Refer to [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) for further details. And you can use **VideoCapture's** `get` function to get the current value of the cam's width or height like:

```
cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
```

Hope this solves your issue.
Thanks.